# Select a list of properties from IGrouping

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I am grouping a bunch of documents by # of days (determines when files go out).
And now I want to retrieve a list of properties from a grouping:

```
    Dim agencyDocumentBatches As List(Of AgencyDocumentBatch) = _agencyDocumentBatchesData.ExecuteQuery(queryParameter, _context.DatabaseName)

    Dim documentBatchesGroupedByDay As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, List(Of AgencyDocumentBatch))) =
            agencyDocumentBatches.GroupBy(Function(d) d.Days)

    For Each documentBatchGroup As IGrouping(Of Integer, List(Of AgencyDocumentBatch)) In documentBatchesGroupedByDay

    Dim addBookingDocumentsParams As New AddBookingDocumentsParams() With
    {
        .BCode = bCode,
        .DueDate = quote.DepartureDate.AddDays(-documentBatchGroup.Key),     'Key = Days before/after departure
        .Documents = documentBatchGroup.Select(Function(d) d.DocumentName).ToList
    }
    _documentDatesData.ExecuteQuery(addBookingDocumentsParams, _context.DatabaseName)
    Next
```

But I see that d.DocumentName is not defined there, it thinks that d is a Collection. I thought iterating through a Grouping would give us access to the elements themselves, am I wrong?

```
Public Class AgencyDocumentBatch

        Public Property ID As Integer

        Public Property DocumentID As Integer

        Public Property Days As Integer

        Public Property AfterDeparture As Boolean

        Public Property DocumentName As String

    End Class
```

Comment: And what does this code do? Creating objects in vain?

Comment: I will send addBookingDocumentsParams to another method for processing. Updated code, but that is besides the problem.

Comment: The first argument is key, so Days must must be key (perhaps, you named it so in LINQ query).

Comment: Sorry typo, I need DocumentName there, will update now

Comment: List of AgencyDocumentBatch

Comment: And `agencyDocumentBatches` is `List(Of AgencyDocumentBatch)`?

Comment: That is correct. When I write this: documentBatchGroup.ToList intellisense says that it is a List of a List of AgencyDocumentbatch

Comment: The `DocumentName` is a property of `AgencyDocumentBatch`. Right? Then `.Select` is correct since you fetch all `DocumentName`s from group. Why you can't see it? Could you update question to show `AgencyDocumentBatch` class?

Comment: So `agencyDocumentBatches` must contain `Days` property, as well as property containing `List(Of AgencyDocumentBatch)` then. Otherwise, `documentBatchesGroupedByDay` would've been `IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, AgencyDocumentBatch))`...

Comment: Then, you'd have to flatten the collection with `documentBatchGroup.SelectMany`. Because you have List of Lists after grouping is done.

Comment: Could it be that documentBatchesGroupedByDay is not correct to be defined as IEnumerable Of Grouping? Intellisense in VB.NET really doesnt help

Comment: It feels like `documentBatchesGroupedByDay` should be `IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, Of AgencyDocumentBatch))`

Comment: Yeah, hovering over over GroupBy says it returns IEnumerable Of IGrouping Of Integer, AgencyDocumentBatch...Maybe rewriting this question in C# would get more hits ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simulation that, I hope, is what you need (some properties are omitted):

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim list = New List(Of AgencyDocumentBatch) From {
            New AgencyDocumentBatch With {.Days = 1, .DocumentName = "Doc1"},
            New AgencyDocumentBatch With {.Days = 2, .DocumentName = "Doc2"},
            New AgencyDocumentBatch With {.Days = 1, .DocumentName = "Doc3"},
            New AgencyDocumentBatch With {.Days = 2, .DocumentName = "Doc4"}
        }

        Dim documentBatchesGroupedByDay = From l In list
                                          Group l By l.Days Into Group

        For Each doc In documentBatchesGroupedByDay
            Dim proxy = New AddBookingDocumentsParams With
            {
                .Documents = doc.Group.Select(Function(a) a.DocumentName).ToList()
            }
        Next

    End Sub

End Module


Class AddBookingDocumentsParams
    Property Documents As List(Of String)
End Class

Public Class AgencyDocumentBatch
    Public Property Days As Integer
    Public Property DocumentName As String
End Class
```

Comment: What is doc.Group?

Comment: It's a key of a group. You could alias it: `Group l By l.Days Into Docs = Group`. Then in code you should use: `.Documents = doc.Docs.Select(...)`.

Comment: I also have a solution, but yours was first. Good approach also.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution without Aliasing:

```
For Each documentBatchGroup As IGrouping(Of Integer, List(Of AgencyDocumentBatch)) In documentBatchesGroupedByDay

        Dim addBookingDocumentsParams As New AddBookingDocumentsParams() With
        {
            .BCode = bCode,
            .DueDate = quote.DepartureDate.AddDays(-documentBatchGroup.Key),     'Key = Days before/after departure
            .Documents = documentBatchGroup(documentBatchGroup.Key).Select(Function(d) d.DocumentName).ToList
        }
        _documentDatesData.ExecuteQuery(addBookingDocumentsParams, _context.DatabaseName)

        Next
```